# Launch execution .exe from my Java tools

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, netbeans, exe

I have my tools with user interfaces in Java.  If I click on a button I want to launch an application. exe in my tools, I have a console where I want to bring the output (console) of .exe.  To do this I have done so:

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    StyledDocument doc = txtResult.getStyledDocument();
    SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    StyleConstants.setForeground(keyWord, Color.RED);

try {

    Process pp=run.exec(PATHEXE);

    BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pp.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader inErr =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pp.getErrorStream()));
    String line = null;
    String lineErr = null;
    while (((line = in.readLine()) != null) ||(lineErr = inErr.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line != null)
             doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), line+"\n", null );
        if(lineErr != null)
              doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), lineErr+"\n", keyWord );
    }

    int exitVal = pp.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
    btRun.setEnabled(true);
}   catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Everything works but I still have some problems:

1. I would like to move the execution. exe on another thread to
   release the user interface during the .exe executing.
2. Reading the output .exe in my tool is only at the end of the ... then run the update I get the output at run-time?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).  It provides the facility to remove a long running task from the EDT, while updating the GUI on the EDT.

Answer (score 0):

Running what you have in a thread is easy:

```
// put up a progress dialog or something here

Runnable backgroundJob = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        final String output = executeJob();  // call your code you provided
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // safely do your updates to the UI here on the Swing Thread
                // hide progress dialog here
                updateUI( output );
            }
        });
    }
};
Thread backgroundThread = new Thread( backgroundJob );
backgroundThread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want your UI to get blocked while .exe is executing then simply do run.exec in a child thread. Moreover you can register a callback function to the child thread which it can callback at the end of execution.